# Drupal 7.14 - grouping site links on search engines

Tags: 7

I am trying to get my sites links, ie. about us, to appear as sublinks of the sites main page. For eg. When you google Drupal, the Downloand & Extend as well as Modules links appear grouped under the main Drupal.org link.

Is there a module that can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are generated by google, not by any module inside of drupal.  googling 'sitelinks' will show you more information about how google creates them for popular sites.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334 from google is a good start.